# Finding the percentage of even numbers in an array

Tags: java, array, iteration

I wrote a method which computes the ratio of even to odd numbers in an array. I know it's a simple piece of code, but I wanted to see if you have any feedback for improving it.

```
public double percentEven(int[] a) {
if(a.length <= 1) {
    return 0.0;
}
double even = 0.0;
for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if(a[i] % 2 == 0) {
        even++;
    } 
}
return (double) (even / a.length) * 100; 
}
```

If the array contains zero elements, or zero even elements, return 0.

Comment: In the case of an array containing 0 elements I would return something else then 0 because an average over 0 elements is not defined. Either an exception or something like -1.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Potential bug: What if the array contains a single element, and it is even?

```
if(a.length <= 1) {
    return 0.0;
}
```

That's what happens.

Easy fix, change to:

```
if(a.length == 0) {
```

---

Your indentation is slightly screwed up, but that might just be a copy-paste error.

---

`double even` should be `int even`.

---

You could use a for-each loop,

```
for (int i : a) {
    if(i % 2 == 0) {
```

---

`int[] a` could be named `int[] array` or `int[] values` or `int[] input`.

---

When using `even` as an `int`, use the following return statement to cast only `even` to a `double`, which will then make it use double division and not int division:

```
return (double) even / a.length * 100;
```

Alternatively you could use:

```
return even * 100.0 / a.length;
```

But I think `return (double) even / a.length * 100;` is better.

Comment: Nice! I implemented all of your suggestions. Thanks for all the great feedback!

Comment: @cody.codes Just out of curiousity: What did you decide to name the `a` variable?

Comment: I usually choose array, but sometimes it confuses me when I don't code for awhile because then I think the object type is "array" when really it's "<insert primitive type>[]." I'll try the other suggestions, like input and value, and see how it goes. Thanks!

Comment: @cody.codes `int[]` actually means "integer array". The name I would recommend the most is probably `values`

Answer (score 10):

If you're using Java 8, `IntStream` can be used to solve the problem along with its `filter` and `count` methods:

```
public static double percentEven(int[] values) {
  IntStream evens = IntStream.of(values).filter(x -> x % 2 == 0);
  return (double) evens.count() / values.length * 100;
}
```

It's not a big win in this particular case, but I think it is a bit cleaner. [Processing Data with Java SE 8 Streams, Part 1](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/ma14-java-se-8-streams-2177646.html) has more examples of where streams can be a powerful tool.

Note that unlike the original code, this will return `NaN` for zero-length arrays. You can of course change it to return 0 instead, if you want.

Comment: NaN is better then 0 because an average of 0 elements is not defined.

Answer (score 4):

I was just surprised by the very short Java 8 solution by mjolka, so I'm giving it a try in Java 7.

```
public double percentEven(int[] values) {
    int even = 0;
    for (int x : values) even += 1 - (x & 1);
    return 100.0 * even / values.length;
}
```

I violated the braces-everywhere convention in order to save 2 lines, but this is still not good enough. Java 8 still wins by 1 line, and that seems impossible to beat.

OTOH the Java 8 solution produces some garbage and I'm afraid it's one or two orders of magnitude slower.

#### Reaction to comments

To those thinking that the following would be clearer

```
even += (x%2 == 0 ? 1 : 0);
```

No, it wouldn't. The former is hard to understand for people unfamiliar with bitwise operation, the latter is hard to understand for people unfamiliar with ternary expressions. While bitwise operations are a bit more exotic, *it makes no sense to reduces everyone's capabilities to the lowest common denominator*. It's no hack, no magic, no code golf, just learn it!

Once we know that `x & 1` extracts the lowest binary digit, we could even argue that it's much cleaner than a conditional expression.

#### Note on optimizations

Division and modulus are pretty expensive and JIT is pretty smart on optimizing them. However, `x % 2` is not the same as `x & 1` for negative numbers, so more work has to be done, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21617265/581205) for some benchmarks.

OTOH `x % 2 == 0` is the same as `(x & 1) == 0`, but I don't know if JIT uses this fact.

---

A maximally optimized code could look like this

```
public double percentEven(int[] values) {
    int even = values.length;
    for (int x : values) even -= x & 1;
    return 100.0 * even / values.length;
}
```

#### Problems with modulus

Using modulus is a bit error prone as both

```
even += x%2 == 1 ? 0 : 1;
```

and

```
even += 1 - x%2;
```

are wrong. The problem is that `%` for negative numbers does not do what we usually need (i.e., rounding towards negative infinity rather than rounding towards zero).

Comment: Shouldn't even be cast to a double on the return statement?

Comment: @Scott Maybe for clarity, but you'd get a warning ("Unnecessary cast from int to double"). The expression evaluates left to right, so it gets cast anyway because of the multiplication by `100.0` and the division takes place last. I guess, adding parentheses would make sense.

Comment: Cool. I didn't notice the significance of you swapping the order of even and 100.0 in your answer

Comment: `even += 1 - (x & 1);` is clever, but very unclear and therefore not good code.  Something like `even += (x%2 == 0 ? 1 : 0)` is just as short, but requires much less thought to figure out.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft To someone proficient with bitwise operations it's perfectly clear. There's no hack there, not even a tiny one, just a use of something less well-known. People ignorant of ternary operators could call your code *very unclear* and require an "if".  My answer is: learn the language well. *It's not clever, it's no corner case, it's no hack, it's something every `HashMap` uses.* It's also much faster, unless JIT can optimize you code to mine (maybe it can, I don't know).

Comment: AFAIK, `x % 2` tends to be optimized into `x & 1`, quite often already at *compile time*. You are right though that it is indeed not really a 'hack', bitwise operations are useful when you need them.

Comment: Speaking of possible minor bitwise optimizations, perhaps `even += 1 - (x & 1);` would be even slightly better as `even += 1 ^ (x & 1);` ?

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg I'm sure that `x % 2` is not the same as `x & 1` (see my answer) and AFAIK there's no similar optimization at compile time. Concerning optimization, I guess that all such expressions take the same time (speedwise, `^` and `-` are the same). I'm also proposing a possibly faster solution above, but I believe that on a modern Intel CPU all variant take one cycle per input element. It can't be less because of the data dependency and it needn't be more because of up to 4 instructions executing in parallel.